# How to avoid gas freezing

Tags: gas

I am from Bangalore. Today I faced strange issue with LPG Indane gas. Gas cylinder suddenly stopped providing gas supply to stove. Today temp 80 F around the city. It's raining all the week. Cylinder is 2 months old, wait of the cylinder seems it will come at least 1 more month. Note Last refilling came for 4 months.

Neighbors suggested to put the cylinder in heat water for few minutes. When I did gas worked for few minutes then stopped again. So Is my gas really freezed? If Yes how can I avoid such situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not, exactly, frozen. Liquified Propane Gas maintains a pressure in the tank proportional to the temperature of the tank/gas. You might have noticed that the tank was quite cold - as you use gas, the liquid in the tank boils to replace it, and the boiling of the liquid takes heat (latent heat of vaporization) so the liquid and the tank cool as gas is used. If they cool too much, the pressure in the tank drops below the pressure you are using form the tank.

If you are managing to cool the tank to the point that (useful) gas pressure is lost while the air temperature is 80°F, you need a larger tank to supply whatever (presumably fairly high-output) burner you are feeding. Or you need to check for what could be a fairly major leak, if this same setup used to work, and suddenly stopped working without you doing something like adding a larger stove or turning on all the burners at once, if you don't normally do that.

Comment: See also this: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/58711/if-my-regular-propane-tank-for-the-house-runs-out-can-i-use-a-bbq-tank-as-a-tem/58726#58726

Comment: Too heavy a gas flow required from too small a tank at too low a temperature to absorb enough heat from the environment to warm the liquid propane. Larger tank is a heat sink that will absorb ambient heat with a large internal evaporative surface area so the liquid doesn't get as cold. Running a gas forge on a 20 gallon tank on a hot day can fit the bill easily for too small, you will have ice on the outside of the tank if it's humid.