# Can I use a 20 lb propane tank to run my propane water heater and do I need a regulator on the tank?

Tags: propane

I’m trying to hook up a 20 lb. propane tank to my propane water heater. Will it work temporarily?

Comment: If the suggested duplicate doesn't work for you try [searching](https://diy.stackexchange.com/search?q=propane+tank+to+heater) - there are dozens of questions here about doing so. Generally, it doesn't go well...

Comment: A useful read: [If my regular propane tank for the house runs out, can I use a BBQ tank as a temporary fix?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/58711/if-my-regular-propane-tank-for-the-house-runs-out-can-i-use-a-bbq-tank-as-a-tem/157788#157788).